# Show Loading gif on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

i want to show Loading.gif into an image that i hover, i already try in css like this :

```
img {background:url(../images/loading.gif) no-repeat center center; }
```

it looks good for all images, but not working on image that i hover on.

so, try to adding a div

```
<div class="load"></div>

.load {background:url(../images/loading.gif) no-repeat center center; }

<div class="detailimage">   
    <img class="mainimage" src="<?php echo $base; ?>/img.php?w=600&h=600&img=images/<?php echo $datadetailproduct['images']; ?>" />
        <ul>
        <?php
            while ($datadetailthumb = mysqli_fetch_assoc($detailthumb)) {
        ?>                      
            <li>
                <img src="<?php echo $base; ?>/img.php?w=75&h=75&img=images/<?php echo $datadetailthumb['thumb']; ?>" />
            </li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

this is my jquery

```
$(".detailimage li img").hover(function(){
    $(".mainimage").attr("src",$(this).attr("src").replace("img.php?w=75&h=75&img=images/", "img.php?w=600&h=600&img=images/"));
    });
```

when i hover the **thumb image**, i want to show loading.gif into .detailimage img("**the main image**")

how to adding that jquery into my recent jquery? **.show(".load")**?

Comment: img:hover {background:url(../images/loading.gif) no-repeat center center; }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this can help you (pure css solution):

http://codepen.io/davidlampon/pen/KpoaNa

I simplified the html and removed all php:

```
<div class="detailimage">       
  <ul>             
    <li>
      <img class="load"></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS (only issue here is you have to specify image dimensions):

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.load {
  width: 316px;
  height: 316px;  
  background:url(http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png) no-repeat center center; 
}

.load:hover{
  background:url(http://www.cuisson.co.uk/templates/cuisson/supersize/slideshow/img/progress.BAK-FOURTH.gif) no-repeat center center; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a jQuery solution, you can see this jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/codotronix/3n6a3ug7/

The HTML

```
<li>
    <img src="http://mlb-s2-p.mlstatic.com/adesivo-parede-infantil-mickey-donald-pateta-disney-baby-16663-MLB20124000600_072014-F.jpg"/>    
</li>
<li class="hoverDiv">
    <img src="http://mlb-s2-p.mlstatic.com/adesivo-parede-infantil-mickey-donald-pateta-disney-baby-16663-MLB20124000600_072014-F.jpg"/>    
</li>
```

The CSS

```
li {
    position: relative;
    list-style:none;
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
}

li img {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}

div.loading {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background: url('http://www.arabianbusiness.com/skins/ab.main/gfx/loading_spinner.gif') no-repeat center center;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
```

and the jQuery

```
$('li').on('mouseenter', function(){
    $(this).append('<div class="loading"></div>');
});

$('li').on('mouseleave', function(){
    $(this).find('div.loading').remove();
});
```

The trick here is to add the loading div on mouseenter and remove it on mouseleave.

Comment: thank you Suman Barick for answering, if the image succes load on page, it will automatically hide the loading.gif? is there any solution for that?

Comment: Do you want to show the loading.gif only if the real image is not loaded and the user still hovers on the li?

Comment: i want user to, if they  hover on the Thumbnail image will show loading.gif on the Big image. after they succesfully load, it will automatically hide the loading.gif and show the Thumbnail image on Big image.